# C# input and output file

Tags: c#

I have code in C#:

```
using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileName,
                                       Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")))
{
    using (System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(
                                           outFileName, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        writer.Write(reader.ReadToEnd());
    }
}
```

it should convert file from iso-8859-1 to utf-8

I'm total noob in C#, can anyone tell me how can I put input and output file for this code?
For example my input file is C:\file.txt and output C:\file2.txt
how should I modify my code for those files?
How my code should look like if I want to save result file to source file C:\file.txt?

Comment: Are you asking about you should write a console program that takes two arguments from the command line? Have you looked at any resource? like [writing a simple command line app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-console?view=vs-2022) or [command line arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/program-structure/main-command-line)  ?